# Appending data.table rows into an empty vector---doing the right data.table thing

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, append, data.table

I'm once again looking at some legacy R code, trying to read the user's mind. It looks like they are using Python style, whereby they define an empty R vector, and then use a for loop to append the results to a vector.

```
library(data.table)
dtable = read.table("path/filename.txt",header=TRUE,sep="\t",check.names=FALSE)
```

After defining this data.table, here is what was 
Here is what is being done:

```
empty_vector <- c()

for(i in 1:nrow(dtable))
{
empty_vector <- append(empty_vector,strsplit(dtable[i,6],":")[[1]][2])
}
```

This is a rather large `data.table`, with +500K rows.

(1) We shouldn't be using a for loop. There is a data.table way to do this.

(2) So, defining an empty vector and appending results to this vector is not R. What is the "R approach" to this?

EDIT: I think the programmer was thinking of something like this in Python:

```
empty_list = []    ## equivalent to R vector

for i in range(10):
    empty_list.append(i)

print(empty_list)   ## now [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

How would someone do something like this, given this is R and we are iterating over rows of a data.table?

Comment: Looks like broken code to me. Please provide example data. But yes should be no reason to loop for this and use append. Append is very slow.

Comment: @CCurtis See my edit. I think what they're trying to do is similar to appending items into an empty list in Python via iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done very simply in R. For each row in the table they are extracting some value from the the text in one column. They then want a vector of those values. Assuming the name of the 6th column of the data table is `colnname6` this becomes

```
emtpy_list = dtable[, strsplit(colnname6, ":")[2]]
```